# Restore GUI workspaces

Tags: gui, console, restore

I accidentally press `Ctrl + Alt + F4` while I was doing normal tasks in my Ubuntu 12.10. The key combination took me to *Console UI*. From the console, I logged in and did `startx` but the output GUI didn't show up with Dash, Launcher or anything (Just background wallpaper). How I can restore my original GUI with all my working applications opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to `Ctrl+Alt+F7` keys toggle between TTYs. Those are basically different consoles you can use to log in. In case there is a desktop running, it's normally on tty7, so just press `Ctrl+Alt+F7` to go back to your desktop.

Comment: Didn't know the default tty was tty7.